# Python map() does not work for list.append()

Tags: python

Here I am appending items into a **list** in an iterative manner:

```
l = []
for i in range(4):
   l.append(i)
print l  # Ans: [0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Where as, if I use **map**() to do the same, I get a different result

```
l = []
map(l.append, range(4))  # Ans: [None, None, None, None]
```

Comment: just fyi there is also `list.extend()` which will append all values in the provided sequence to the list, e.g. `list.extend(range(4))`

Comment: @mfitzp yes, I have already explored list.append(). But curious to know why map() did not work in this case.

Comment: not `list.append()` ...`list.extend()` — the first adds a single element to a list, the second adds a list (or any iterable) to the list. As for map, it *did* work, the list was updated (look at it the value of `l` after the map). The output of map contains the return value of `list.append()`, which is *always* `None`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python `map` returns the values returned for each function call in a list (or a generator).

In this case `list.append` returns `None`.
Also `l` is mutable, so it should contain the items.